# How to keep merging data frames using a function in R?

Tags: r, function, merge

I have six data frames ie df1,df2,df3,df4,df5 and df6. I want merge them using function in the following manner:

df1<-data.frame(c(1:1000))

df2<-data.frame(c(1:10000))

df3<-data.frame(c(1:50000))

df4<-data.frame(c(1:3000))

df5<-data.frame(c(1:70000))

df6<-data.frame(c(1:90000))

First the function will merge df1 with df2 and it will create a data frame with the merged values of df1 & df2, then it will do the same for df1 and df3 and df1 and df4, and so on. Once this process is over it repeats the same process for df2,df3,df4,df5,df6.  Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `merge`.  In the OP's post, `by` variable is not mentioned, so it is also showed in the code below

```
v1 <- paste0("df", 1:6)
res <- lapply(seq_along(v1), function(i) Reduce(function(...) 
           merge(...), mget(v1[i:length(v1)], envir = .GlobalEnv)))
```

Comment: If I use this function it gives this error :Error in Reduce(function(...) merge(..., mget(v1[i:length(v1)]))) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default

Comment: @sidsatam  I think there was a mismatching `)`.  Please check it now

Comment: it now giving me following error:    Error: value for ‘df1’ not found

Comment: @sidsatam  You didn't providie even a reproducible example.  So, please update your post with an example for others to work on

Comment: @sidsatam  Based on the error, it means you don't have an object 'df1'.  So, the error is in your part and not in the code.  Your description says that you have `df1,df2,df3,df4,df5 and df6`. .

Comment: @sidsatam  You need to specify the `envir`.  I corrected it.  THanks for the comments.  Also, when you create an example, specify the column names as well ie. `df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(1:1000))` without that it will give something unexpected

Comment: How do I turn res into a dataframe?

Comment: @sidsatam  `res` is a `list` of `data.frames`.  If you want a single data.frame with each one of them have the same column names, then `do.call(rbind, res)`  If they have different column names, and you want it to be different columns, then `library(dplyr); bind_rows(res)`

Comment: @sidsatam  Sorry, Sid, you can post your new questions as a new post.  I already answered the question you originally posted